# ionic post request blocked by cors while postman works fine Ionic 4

Tags: angular, cors, ionic4

I am using ionic 4 with angular 7 . Have a post request that keeps triggering the following error, but when I test this post request in Postman it works fine:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://examplecode/backend/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

my post request:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
  sendCodeToServer(data) {
    this.http.post(endpoindURL, data, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).toPromise().then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

all I am sending is this { "id" : 1111111 }.
As I said it works fine on Postman, but in my app I keep getting the error. The server already has several measures so this wouldn't happen

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");         

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Not sure how to fix it, the servers seems fine and the request seems fine, and works in postman as well, just never works on the mobile app.

Comment: CORS doesnt apply to postman, you wont see an error there. In what language/framework is your backend implemented?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo php

Comment: Could you please add a SS of the failed HTTP request with its details? (Network tabs view of your browser debugger)

Comment: What @Jota.Toledo said. In particular you probably want to check the HTTP status code of the response. If it’s a 4xx or 5xx error, then it’s likely the response is being sent without the custom response headers your server code’s setting.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo it is a 403 forbidden error, apparently it is working in other phones but not in mine, my phone is huawei 20 lite matte and  has 8.1.0, I am sitll not sure why it just won't work with my phone

Comment: @sideshowbarker it is a 403 forbidden error, apparently it is working in other phones but not in mine, my phone is huawei 20 lite matte and has 8.1.0, I am sitll not sure why it just won't work with my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My headers in PHP which I have used with Ionic. Hope this helps.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```